# How to prevent keyboard changing from Numbers to Alphabet when the space key is touched?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextfield

I have `UITextFields` on a table to enter values.
Some of these fields accept only numbers. I am using `UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation` for the keyboardType, and `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to filter the characters.

Also, all the corrections are disabled:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
textField.autocorrectionType =  UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.autocapitalizationType =  UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

On the numeric only fields, when the space key is touched, the keyboard changes to Alphabet.
I know that this is the default behavior.
I want to ignore the space key, and don't want the keyboard type change.

Is there some way to change this default behavior?

PS: the other numeric keyboard types are not an option. I need the Punctuation!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to modify the keyboard behavior.

However, you could implement the [textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991-CH3-SW9) from the UITextFieldDelegate protocol to intercept the space (and apostrophe) like this and it seems to work:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([string isEqualToString:@" "] || [string isEqualToString:@"'"]) {
        NSMutableString *updatedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
        [updatedString insertString:string atIndex:range.location];
        textField.text = updatedString;
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```