# iPhone UITextField Keyboard Space Switching Layout

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, keyboard-layout

I want the user to be able to type in only numbers and spaces. I set the keyboardType `textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;` but if a user hits space, the keyboard layout switches to letters.

So the user has to switch after each space to the number layout which I want to stop.
I know I can stop entering any spaces by the textfield delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` or or the NumberPad Layout but I want the spaces to display.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially you could use the keyboard layout suggested [here](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) but instead of a "Done" button you could include a "_" spacebar button? This has the added benefit of preventing the user from selecting any punctuation.

An alternate answer to specifically the behavior you're seeing is found in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071561/how-to-prevent-keyboard-changing-from-numbers-to-alphabet-when-the-space-key-is-t/2071778#2071778).